# get multiple sql results in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

For statistics I would like to get the number of valid inapp purchase per airline code per months. For a single month I do already have a query:

```
SELECT 
    AirlineCode, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT AppUser.Id) AppUser
FROM [followme.aero.live].[dbo].[AppUser]
JOIN [followme.aero.live].[dbo].[UserInAppPurchase]
ON AppUser.Id = UserInAppPurchase.UserId
WHERE ValidTo > '2018-01-01' AND PurchaseDate < '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY AirlineCode 
ORDER BY AppUser DESC;
```

That would give me the January data. What I would like to get is the output not only for January but also for February, March and so on in 2018 in one single table.

How would I manage to do that?

Background:

In our database we have two tables, `AppUser` and `UserInAppPurchase`.

A user may or may not have inapp purchases in the table. A user may also have multiple entries here.

Important columns are `AppUser.AirlineCode`, `UserInAppPurchase.ValidTo` and `UserInAppPurchase.PurchaseDate`.

As I said, an `AppUser` may have multiple table entries or non at all. I'd like to check if one `AppUser` has at least one inapp purchase valid > than month x, then sum that per `AirlineCode` per month.

- x-axis: `AirlineCode`
- y-axis: Months of the year

We are using mssql

Comment: Remove the date restriction from the WHERE clause. Instead add month (and year) to the GROUP BY clause, and to the SELECT list.

Comment: What are the conditions for a user to be listed in a particular month? Your condition for January seems to be any valid date to from january onwards (even further than 2018-01-31), so this isn't as simple as it seems.

Comment: @EzLo this would give me the actual number of valid subscriptions: ValidTo is bigger than January = meaning they are still running and PurchaseDate is before January = meaning the purchase has been made before. Resulting in the number of valid subscription I have in January made in the past and valid into the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each purchase might be computed for different months, you can't simply `GROUP BY`, you will have to *somehow* multiply each record for each month that applies before grouping.

You can use a CTE to generate month reference dates, then join against these. Note that I added the year of each month, you can omit if you don't need it (or just generate months up to 2018-12-01).

```
;WITH MonthsStartDates AS
(
    SELECT
        MonthStartDate = CONVERT(DATE, '2018-01-01')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        MonthStartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, M.MonthStartDate)
    FROM
        MonthsStartDates AS M
    WHERE
        M.MonthStartDate <= '2020-01-01'
)
SELECT 
    AirlineCode,
    Year = DATEPART(YEAR, M.MonthStartDate),
    Month = DATEPART(MONTH, M.MonthStartDate),
    AppUser = COUNT(DISTINCT AppUser.Id)
FROM 
    [followme.aero.live].[dbo].[AppUser]
    INNER JOIN [followme.aero.live].[dbo].[UserInAppPurchase] ON AppUser.Id = UserInAppPurchase.UserId
    INNER JOIN MonthsStartDates AS M ON
        PurchaseDate < M.MonthStartDate AND
        ValidTo > M.MonthStartDate
GROUP BY 
    AirlineCode,
    DATEPART(YEAR, M.MonthStartDate),
    DATEPART(MONTH, M.MonthStartDate)
```

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for. One more thing: How would it be able to rotate the table, to have the months in the y-axis and AirlineCode in the x-axis?

Comment: @Andreas to change row values to columns you need to use the PIVOT function. You can't pivot 2 columns easily though so you may want to concatenate year and month in a varchar column then pivot this one. Also you might need to hard-code the years and months you want to pivot (or use dynamic SQL pivot, which is a little bit more complex). There are many examples of pivot operator here in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Add `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` for `PurchaseDate` and add them to `GROUP BY` clause. Also change PurchaseDate range if you want to see the data from '2018-01-01'.
Check this sample :

```
SELECT
    AirlineCode
    ,YEAR(PurchaseDate) PurchaseYear
    ,MONTH(PurchaseDate) PurchaseMonth
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT AppUser.Id) AppUser
FROM [followme.aero.live].[dbo].[AppUser]
JOIN [followme.aero.live].[dbo].[UserInAppPurchase]
    ON AppUser.Id = UserInAppPurchase.UserId
WHERE ValidTo > '2018-01-01'
AND ( PurchaseDate >= '2018-01-01' AND PurchaseDate <= '2018-12-31')
GROUP BY AirlineCode,
    ,YEAR(PurchaseDate) 
    ,MONTH(PurchaseDate) 
ORDER BY AppUser DESC;
```